# Serilog is not creating the Log table

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

Actually I have this code in C# with net framework 4.7.2 in a console app:

```cs
internal class Program 
{
    private static string connectionString 
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["defaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        var sqlLoggerOptions = new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
                    {
                        TableName = "Logs",
                        BatchPostingLimit = 1,
                        BatchPeriod = new TimeSpan(2, 14, 18),
                        AutoCreateSqlTable = true,
                        SchemaName = "Logger",
                    };
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                        .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Information)
                        .WriteTo.File("log.txt", LogEventLevel.Fatal, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 10)
                        .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, sqlLoggerOptions) //Aquí se añade el Sink
        .CreateLogger();
        logger.Verbose("Mensaje Verbose");
        logger.Debug("Mensaje Debug");
        logger.Information("Mensaje Information");
        logger.Warning("Mensaje Warning");
        logger.Error("Mensaje Error");
        logger.Fatal("Mensaje Fatal");
    }
}
```

and this is my appconfig:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration> 
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/> 
  </startup>  
  <connectionStrings> 
    <add name="defaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MATIAS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Prueba;Integrated Security=True;"/> 
  </connectionStrings>  
  <runtime> 
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
      <dependentAssembly> 
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>  
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.21.0.0" newVersion="6.21.0.0"/> 
      </dependentAssembly>  
      <dependentAssembly> 
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Identity.Client" publicKeyToken="0a613f4dd989e8ae" culture="neutral"/>  
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.45.0.0" newVersion="4.45.0.0"/> 
      </dependentAssembly>  
      <dependentAssembly> 
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>  
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/> 
      </dependentAssembly>  
      <dependentAssembly> 
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>  
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1"/> 
      </dependentAssembly>  
      <dependentAssembly> 
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>  
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0"/> 
      </dependentAssembly>  
      <dependentAssembly> 
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encodings.Web" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>  
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.1" newVersion="4.0.5.1"/> 
      </dependentAssembly>  
      <dependentAssembly> 
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>  
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0"/> 
      </dependentAssembly>  
      <dependentAssembly> 
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>  
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1"/> 
      </dependentAssembly>  
      <dependentAssembly> 
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>  
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/> 
      </dependentAssembly>  
      <dependentAssembly> 
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>  
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2"/> 
      </dependentAssembly> 
    </assemblyBinding> 
  </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

But Serilog it is not creating the table "Logs", I have been trying everything, in a net 6 proyect, on another computer and it doesn't work. The connection string is okay match with the server name in SQL Server management studio and I have a database called `UniversityDB`.

PD: Sorry for my English.

Comment: Have you created the schema? Note that I don't use this Serilog MSSQL implementation so I'm just  guessing here.

Comment: Yes, i created the 'Logger' schema in my database.

Comment: I don't have the `.CreateLogger();` in my code, can you try commenting that line out?